# mysql inner join random syntax error

Tags: mysql, inner-join

```
(SELECT * FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 
ON table1.id = table2.id) 
AS t1 
JOIN (SELECT ROUND(RAND() * (SELECT MAX(table1.id) FROM table1)) AS id) 
AS t2 
WHERE t1.id >= t2.id 
LIMIT 1)
```

I try to use `RAND()` `max(id)` to get a random mysql result, but get a `#1064` error.

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS t1 JOIN (SELECT ROUND(RAND() * (SELECT MAX(table1.id) FROM table1))' at line 1`

Where is the problem? thanks.

Comment: is this the whole query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(assuming that this code snippet is an entire query)

May be wrong but your statement does not have a SELECT ... in short it looks like this:

t1 JOIN t2 WHERE ...

There is no SELECT something FROM t1 JOIN t2 WHERE ...

Not sure if I make myself clear...

Addendum:

Not sure what you re trying to achieve, but this code bellow returns random IDs from your tables (variation of your query) so perhaps you can use it. A bit messy perhaps but then again I have no idea what are you trying to achieve :).

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT table1.id as id1 
    FROM table1 
    INNER JOIN table2 
    ON table1.id = table2.id)  as t1
JOIN (
  (SELECT ROUND(RAND() * (SELECT MAX(table1.id) FROM table1)) AS id2) 
AS t2 )
WHERE t1.id1 >= t2.id2
LIMIT 1
```

You can select id1 or id2 instead of *, depending on what is your goal...

Comment: problem is that parser does not recognize what it is supposed to do because there is no SELECT at the beginning of a statement - SELECT in first parenthesis is treated as a sub query.

Answer (score 0):

(assuming that this code snippet is part of a bigger query)

The problem is this subquery:

```
(SELECT * FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 
ON table1.id = table2.id) 
AS t1
```

Running it alone:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
  INNER JOIN table2 
  ON table1.id = table2.id ;
```

will give no error but it will show/return at least 2 columns with same name (`id`). This is causing the conflict when you are trying to include it as a subquery in a bigger query.